# Struggling with how to refresh event listeners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, event-listener

Did an extensive search to find an answer but came up empty, so here goes. In the below JSFiddle, you'll notice that when you click on the word "shampoo" it appears at the top of my list as it's intended to. But when you click it again, it re-animates! I've learned this is because the event listeners are set when the DOM first loads, and is not refreshed. So, it still thinks it has a class of ".done". I cannot figure out how to fix this!

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uq5o5suv/1/

Relevant Javascript:

```
// Handles adding entries back into the list
$(".done p").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("class", "item not-done");
    $(this).parent().hide().prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative way is using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) (the handler is executed at most once per element per event type), something like this,

```
$(".done p").one('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().attr("class", "item not-done");
  $(this).parent().hide().prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to unbind the click handler, so the following should work:

```
$(".done p").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("class", "item not-done");
    $(this).parent().hide().prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');
    $(this).unbind('click');
});
```

Comment: Wow, well that worked! But I have no idea why. I thought the problem had to do with my Javascript ALWAYS thinking it had the class .done because that's what it had when the page loaded.

Comment: Naw, it's because .click() is attached to the element and never goes away (in the original code). So when you click the first time, it fires, when you click the second time, it fires and so on. To make it only fire the first time, we need to remove the handler from the individual element (`$(this)`) so that the click handler is no longer registered with that individual element.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Handles new entry submissions
    $('.entry-form').submit(function(event) {
        var entryValue = $(".entry").val();
        // if `entryValue` _not_ have class `not-done` ,
        // prepend `done` having `entryValue` to `.list` ,
        // add class `not-done`
        if (!$(".not-done:contains(" + entryValue + ")").is("*")) {
          var elem = $(".done:contains(" + entryValue + ")");
                    elem.attr("class", "item not-done")
                    .prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');

        } else {
          // else detach `done` class having `entryValue` from `DOM`
          console.log(entryValue + " already listed");
          $(".done:contains(" + entryValue + ")").detach()
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.entry-form')[0].reset();
    });

    // Handles adding entries back into the list
    $(".done p").click(function() {
        $(this).parent().attr("class", "item not-done")
       .hide().prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // Handles new entry submissions
 $('.entry-form').submit(function(event) {
        var entryValue = $(".entry").val();
        if (!$(".not-done:contains("+entryValue+")").is("*")) {
          var elem = $(".done:contains("+entryValue+")");
                    elem.attr("class", "item not-done")
        .prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');

        } else {
          console.log(entryValue + " already listed");
          $(".done:contains("+entryValue+")").detach()
        }
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.entry-form')[0].reset();
 });

 // Handles adding entries back into the list
 $(".done p").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().attr("class", "item not-done")
  .hide().prependTo('.list').fadeIn('.5s');
 });
});
```

```css
/**
 * Eric Meyer's Reset CSS v2.0 (http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
 font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
 font-weight: 300;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}


body {
 background-color: grey;
 background-size: cover;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
 margin: 0 20%;
 height: 100%;
}

.header {
 height: 2em;
 background-color: white;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.header h2 {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.main h1 {
 text-align: center;
 margin: 1em 0;
 font-family: "Libre Bakersville";
 font-weight: 700;
 font-size: 2em;
 color: white;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.entry-form {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
 height: 2em;
 border-radius: 2em;
 width: 100%;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset -0px -1px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset -0px -1px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
 box-shadow: inset -0px -1px 8px -2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}

.entry {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 height: 2em;
 width: 80%;
 margin-left: 2em;
 border: none;
 font-size: 1em;
 color: #fff;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.entry::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: #fff;
}

.entry:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
   color: #fff;  
}

.entry::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
   color: #fff;  
}

.entry:-ms-input-placeholder {  
   color: #fff;  
}

.entry, .submit {
 outline: none;
}

.submit {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
 border: 1px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 1em;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1em;
 padding: .1em 1em;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 25px;
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.submit:hover {
 background-color: #fff;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 -webkit-transition: background-color .25s ease, color .1s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color .25s ease, color .1s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color .25s ease, color .1s ease;
    transition: background-color .25s ease, color .1s ease;
}

.list {
 margin: 2em 20%;
}

.item {
 margin: .33em 0;
 height: 1.75em;
}

.not-done {
/* background-color: rgba(365,365,365,.8);
*/ border-radius: 2em;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px -1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(365,365,365,.8), rgba(235,235,235,.8));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(365,365,365,.8), rgba(235,235,235,.8));
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(365,365,365,.8), rgba(235,235,235,.8));
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(365,365,365,.8), rgba(235,235,235,.8));
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(365,365,365,.8), rgba(235,235,235,.8));
}

.checkbox {
 width: .75em;
 height: .75em;
 margin: 0 .75em;
 background-color: rgba(365,365,365,.7);
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);
 border-radius: .2em;
}

.checkbox, .item p {
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 display: inline-block;
}

.not-done p {

}

.done .checkbox {
 background-color: initial;
}

.done a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

.done a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>The Fucking Milk</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/script.js"></script>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400|Libre+Baskerville:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="header">
  <div class="container">
   <h2>Made by @taykcrane</h2>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="container">
   <h1>The Fucking Milk</h1>
   <form class="entry-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Go ahead. Add a new item to your shopping list here." class="entry">
    <input type="submit" value="Enter" class="submit">
   </form>
   <div class="list">
    <div class="item not-done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p><a href="#">almond milk</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item not-done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p>bananas</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item not-done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p>peanut butter</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item not-done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p>jelly</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item not-done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p>whole wheat bread</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p><a href="#">shampoo</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="item done">
     <div class="checkbox"></div>
     <p><a href="#">comb</a></p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```